# Docker Windows bridge ip conflict

Tags: windows, docker

I have used Docker on a Linux machine and just started using it on Windows too.

I am on a unfortunate location where they use 172.17.0.0/16 subnet that conflicts with default Docker bridge subnet.

```
C:\>docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "d6ae8949e4e098ad4443ba2cd72bed5f9f96d81f5d2d00197b9443b8a8c1d1f6"
,
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I know there is an option for Linux (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ bip) to change this. But is there also an option for Windows?

PS. I have tried adding `"bip": "10.11.12.0/24"` to JSON Daemon configuration but Docker crashes on startup:

Comment: `bip` is expected to work. Would you mind posting more details or opening an issue here? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues

Comment: This issue https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/118